# Someway of removing internal links from Wikipedia XML files?

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia, populate

If I have downloaded Wikipedia XML dumps, is there any way of removing all of the internal links from within an XML file?

Thanks

Comment: Which method did you settle on, out of curiosity?

Comment: Not yet decided, because unfortunately just removing the [[ doesn't work because of the extra formatting Wikipedia does.  I'm not too confident on bots yet, so it's on hold at the moment, until I can pay someone to do it!  So, no method!  Thanks for all the help everyone, very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do, if you are importing them into a local wiki, is to import all the files you want, then use a robot (eg. [pywikipediabot](http://pywikipediabot.sourceforge.net/) is easy to use) to get rid of all the internal links.

Comment: Better yet, if your wiki is going to be used somewhere that you have internet access, you could change all the internal links to [[wikipedia:PageName|PageName]], then they would refer back to their original articles.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia database dumps and information about using them are located here: [Wikipedia:Database download](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download). You should do this instead of writing a script to scrape Wikipedia.

Comment: Yeah found that, sorry I got my question wrong really!  How can I remove the internal links from the xml files?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use XSLT to transform the XML file into another XML file.

Answer (score -1):

You could do a search and replace in your favorite text editor, replacing [[ and ]] with nothing.